# Ошибка при синхронизированом POST запросе через Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Реализую POST запрос через  Retrofit 2 используя асинхронный и синхронный метод.
 `call.enqueue` - выполняется.
 `call.execute` - выдает ошибку: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick` и т.д.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.IOException;
import retrofit.Call;
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit.Response;
import retrofit.Retrofit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String url = "http://mysite.org";
    private String respons;
    private String tokez;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) throws IOException {

    // getTokez();
        getResponzi();


    }

    public   void getTokez() throws IOException {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RetrofitAPI service = retrofit.create(RetrofitAPI.class);
        TokenRequest tokenRequest=new TokenRequest();
        tokenRequest.setEmail("vasja@gmail.com");
        tokenRequest.setPassword("vasja1111");
        tokenRequest.setCsrf_login("4bf023fa-879f-4fa5-b64d-594d88c17f84");
        tokenRequest.setG_recaptha_response("");
        tokenRequest.setRememberMe(1);
        Call<TokenResponse> call = service.getRequestAccess(tokenRequest);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<TokenResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<TokenResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                try {
                    int statusCode=response.code();
                    TokenResponse result = response.body();
                    respons=new Gson().toJson(result);
                    tokez=result.getAuthTokez();
                    Log.d("PostTokez","StatusCode="+statusCode);
                    Log.d("PostTokez", "Respons=" + respons);
                    Log.d("PostTokez", "Tokez="+tokez);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("PostTokez", "There is an error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

                Log.d("onFailure", t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
    //Синхронный запрос
    public  void getResponzi() throws IOException {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        RetrofitAPI service = retrofit.create(RetrofitAPI.class);
        TokenRequest tokenRequest=new TokenRequest();
        tokenRequest.setEmail("vasja@gmail.com");
        tokenRequest.setPassword("vasja1111");
        tokenRequest.setCsrf_login("4bf023fa-879f-4fa5-b64d-594d88c17f84");
        tokenRequest.setG_recaptha_response("");
        tokenRequest.setRememberMe(1);
        Call<TokenResponse> call1 = service.getRequestAccess(tokenRequest);
        Response response = call1.execute();
             }
}
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5609)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22259)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

Comment: Приложите код, связанный с ошибкой, и стектрейс к вопросу, а не ссылкой на внешний источник.

Comment: Полный стектрейс нужен, а не огрызок, в котором даже отсылок к вашему коду нет.

Answer (score 3):

`Response response = call1.execute();` - в основном потоке нельзя выполнять синхронные вызовы, т.к. это блокирует основной поток

Используйте асинхронный вызов через `call1.enqueue()` и обрабатывайте ответ в `callback`

[Примеры](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests)

```
Call<TokenResponse> call1 = service.getRequestAccess(tokenRequest);
call1.enqueue(new Callback<TokenResponse>() {  
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<TokenResponse> call, Response<TokenResponse> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            // тут код при успешном ответе
            // получение ответа
            TokenResponse response = response.body();
        } else {
            // если не ок то...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Task>> call, Throwable t) {
        // обработка fail
    }
}
```